# XSLT parsing our more data than I'm selecting

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd really appreciate any help on understanding why I'm getting more data out of the transformation than I'm actually selecting in the stylesheet. So here's my XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<e:root xmlns:e="http://www.yahoo.com">
  <e:first>Hi</e:first>
  <e:cds>
    <e:cd>
      <e:title>Eric</e:title>
    </e:cd>
    <e:cd>
      <e:title>Tara</e:title>
    </e:cd>
  </e:cds>
</e:root>
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:e="http://www.yahoo.com" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e:cd">
      <xsl:element name="T"><xsl:value-of select="e:title"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  Hi

    <T>Eric</T>
    <T>Tara</T>
```

How do I stop the transformation from selecting out the `<e:first>` node? I'm not explicitly asking for it in the transform, yet it's coming out in my result (with the text 'Hi'). I'm going crazy trying to understand why. Thank you very much, in advance, for any help offered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of [XSLT's built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Since you're using `xsl:value-of` in your `e:cd` template you can just add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Another alternative is to narrow the scope of what you're processing:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="e:root/e:cds"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, unless you're creating an element name dynamically, there's no reason to use `xsl:element`...

```
<T><xsl:value-of select="e:title"/></T>
```